# how to add landscape page, new page, and delete page in web-addins

Tags: office-js, office-addins, word-addins

I am working on word web addins , i am facing difficulty in implementing the below features in addins

create landscape page , add new page with left margin , add new page,  delete page  after current selection , there is no any api provided for implementing this features using js

Is there any way to implement this?

I have tried to create new page but it add page break to create a new page, whenever i delete the the first page(from where i have created new page) it auto delete the new created page

```
function insertNewPage() {
  return Word.run(async (context) => {
    try {
      let range = context.document.getSelection();
      range.insertBreak(Word.BreakType.page, Word.InsertLocation.after);
      // range.insertBreak(Word.BreakType.sectionNext, Word.InsertLocation.after);
      await context.sync();
      sendNotification("Page Added", "success");
    } catch (error) {
      sendNotification("Error: Please try again", "error");
    }
  });
}
function deletePage() { 
  return Word.run(async (context) => {
    try {
      let range = context.document.getSelection();
      let pageRange = range.parentBody.getRange();
      pageRange.delete();
      await context.sync();
      sendNotification("Success", "success");
    } catch (error) {
      // console.log(error);
      // if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
      //   console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
      // }
      sendNotification("Error: Please try again", "error");
    }
  });
}
```